# VBA in Excel works fine in Windows 2007 machine, but not Windows 10

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I have this bit of VBA

```
Sub populateChartData()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim finalRowSheet2 As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim price As Double
Dim cnt As Integer

With Worksheets("Data")
Set Sheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
finalRowSheet2 = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To 5
    For j = 2 To 5
        price = 0
        cnt = 0
        For k = 2 To finalRowSheet2
            Sheet2.Cells(i, 5) = "'" & Sheet2.Cells(i, 5)
            If .Cells(i, 1) = CInt(Right(Sheet2.Cells(k, 5), 4)) And _
               .Cells(1, j) = Sheet2.Cells(k, 4) Then
                   price = price + Sheet2.Cells(k, 3) 'Col 7 if weighting is used
                   cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next k
        If cnt = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, j) = 0
        Else
            .Cells(i, j) = price / cnt
        End If
    Next j

Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
address1    3.19 mi $1,250  studio  5/1/2017
address2    3.38 mi $950    studio  7/1/2017
address3    3.48 mi $725    studio  3/1/2017
address4    3.51 mi $850    studio  7/1/2017
```

It works as intended on a Windows 2007 machine. But when used on a Windows 10 machine it produces a `Type Mismatch` Error on this line

```
If .Cells(i, 1) = CInt(Right(Sheet2.Cells(k, 5), 4)) And _
           .Cells(1, j) = Sheet2.Cells(k, 4) Then
```

I have tried going into `Control Panel >> Clock, Language and Region >> Region and Language` to set the language to English, but it was already set to English. I had read that this could be the problem. I have also tried to experiment with changing the types of the variables, but so far the error continues to be thrown on the Windows 10 machine. I would like this code to work on both Windows operating system without this error.

Comment: Check the `thausands separator` and the `decimal separator` of both versions. It is in the Regional Options, in the Control Panel.

Comment: I will take a look and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code in both versions:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print "Decimal -> "; Application.DecimalSeparator
    Debug.Print "Thausand -> "; Application.ThousandsSeparator
End Sub
```

If the result is different, you know what to do. You may read more about this trick here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa215774(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I'll have a look later today. This is actually on a client's computer and already have an email out to him. I will certainly let you know either way.

Comment: Going the Control Panel route, the settings you mention appear identical. Will running this code possibly give a different answer anyway?

Comment: I'm sorry. I get the same results in each.

Comment: @MattCremeens - are you copying just the code and putting it in an Excel file or you are copying the Excel file with the code as well?

Comment: The entire workbook, code and all, is on both machines. At the moment, it is appearing that taking all variable declarations out, removing `Option Explicit` and replacing `CInt` with `Val` might be working, but I have no real idea as to why.

Comment: You just copy the excel workbook between the machines and it works on `A` but it does not work on `B`?